# $R^2\setminus K, K$ compact, is not simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness

So, I think I'm aware of the general idea of how to do this. $K$ is compact, hence closed and bounded, so there is some circle of finite radius, say $r$, that wraps around $K$. This loop isn't null homotopic in $R^2\setminus K$.

It's that last bit, even though I see it, I'm having trouble writing it down rigorously. It seems that any homotopy $f_t:I \to R^2\setminus K$ where $f_1$ is the loop I mentioned and $f_0$ is the trivial loop, would have to have points from $K$ in its image for some $t$. Can you help me make this more rigorous?

Comment: Use `\setminus` for the \ (I think) you want to make.

Comment: Note: $\varnothing$ is compact, and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \varnothing$ is simply connected. Leaving that case aside, can you show it if $K$ consists of a single point?

Comment: Hint: Winding number

Comment: Do you know that the loop $I:\to S^1, t\mapsto(\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$ is not nullhomotopic? That can be used to show that your loop in $\Bbb R^2\setminus K$ is not null-homotopic.